# can't delete a memory location

Tags: c, memory-management

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct data {
    int a, b;
} Data ;

struct node {
    Data info;
    int priority;
    struct node *link;
};
typedef struct node* Node;

void insert(Node header, int pr, Data el) {
    Node cur = header;
    Node tmp = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    tmp->info = el;
    tmp->priority = pr;
    //descending <=
    while (cur->link != NULL && pr >= cur->link->priority)
        cur = cur->link;
    tmp->link = cur->link;
    cur->link = tmp;
}

Node delete(Node header) {
    Node tmp;
    if (header->link == NULL)
        printf("Empty priority queue");
    else {
        tmp = header->link;
        header->link = tmp->link;
        free(tmp);
        return tmp;
    }
}

void display(Node head) {
    Node cur = head->link;
    while (cur != NULL) {
        printf("%d ", cur->priority);
        cur = cur->link;
    }

}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    Data d;
    Node tmp;
    Node head = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    head->link = NULL;

    insert(head, 3, d);

    insert(head, 2, d);
    insert(head, 1, d);
while (head->link != NULL) {

    tmp = delete(head);
    printf("%d ", tmp->priority);
}



    return 0;
}
```

The output of this is 1 2 3. but in delete i deallocated the memory(free(tmp)) and then returned tmp. why is it tmp still printing in main function. using gcc compiler

Comment: Why is your code accessing memory that has already been `free()`'ed? Why is the `delete()` function returning a pointer to `free()`'ed memory in the first place?

Comment: As a side note, not sure that I particularly like the Node typedef. If someone only looks at your function definition, at a glance it looks like you're passing by value rather than by reference. Your usage of typedef here decreases readability. Just my opinion though :)

Comment: @Demian: I agree, but my prof in college used to do the same thing. I hated it, but some people seem to like to hide pointers in typedefs.

Answer (score 7):

`delete`/`free` don't necessarily zero out memory. They can mark it as deallocated for the memory allocator. The memory allocator is then free to allocate it again in another `new`/`malloc` call. The point is, as soon as you freed the memory block, you should not access it. It's *undefined behavior*. Undefined behavior means it may crash, return garbage, return old value, blow up your computer, [become a skynet](http://xkcd.com/534/), or anything else, depending on the implementation/situation.

If you want to store sensitive information like cryptographic keys/passwords in memory as short as possible, you should fill the memory with something else yourself before freeing it up (e.g. by calling [`SecureZeroMemory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366877%28VS.85%29.aspx) in Windows).